# maven-build not creating .war file

Tags: eclipse, maven-3

windows 7 pro
eclipse oxygen
java jdk1.8.0_172
tomcat 8.5.31
maven 3.5.3

created a project using maven-archetype-webapp and 
java 1.8
dynamic-web-module 3.1

relevant POM fragment

```
<build>
  <finalName>MyWebApp</finalName>
  <directory>target</directory>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build
```

all seems alright until I try to create a war-file.
maven->build  does not create a ./target/MyWebApp.war file as I'd expect - instead I get a ./target/m2e-wtp and some other stuff I'm not used to seeing.
Ach!

Also, this is a new instance of a new version of Eclipse on a new machine, so there's quite possibly some subtle configuration waggle that I wiggled or visa versa.

Any ideas?  I cast my fate upon the Winds of Fate (sic SOF)

TIA,

code_warrior

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `packaging` section of your pom says `war`. Also when building with eclipse make sure to select the `package` or `verify` goal.